How can we use the TailChainSwapMoveSelectorConfig with the AnchorShadow variable in the OptaPlanner or Timefold projects?
I've added the following default configurations for using TailChainSwapMoveSelectorConfig:
`TailChainSwapMoveSelectorConfig tailChainSwapMoveSelectorConfig = new TailChainSwapMoveSelectorConfig();
EntitySelectorConfig entitySelectorConfig = new EntitySelectorConfig();
entitySelectorConfig.setEntityClass(Polygon.class);
    ValueSelectorConfig valueSelectorConfig = new ValueSelectorConfig();
    valueSelectorConfig.setVariableName("previousCrewMemberOrPolygon");

    tailChainSwapMoveSelectorConfig.setEntitySelectorConfig(entitySelectorConfig);
    tailChainSwapMoveSelectorConfig.setValueSelectorConfig(valueSelectorConfig);

    LocalSearchPhaseConfig localSearchPhaseConfig = new LocalSearchPhaseConfig();
    localSearchPhaseConfig.setLocalSearchType(LocalSearchType.TABU_SEARCH);
    localSearchPhaseConfig.setMoveSelectorConfig(tailChainSwapMoveSelectorConfig);`

My planning solution list has more than 2000 entries, With these data Local Search is terminating after one steps with giving any best solution.
However, there is no improvement in the planning by adding these configurations.
If anyone know about the implementation of TailChainSwapMoveSelectorConfig, please share the configuration details or any other relevant information that might help.
Thank you.

Why are you adding this move? Why are you specifying the entity and value selectors at all? Are you sure your constraints do what they're supposed to do? Are you sure you haven't configured the solver to terminate after one step - because that is certainly not the default behavior.
This question is missing relevant information, and most likely mixing several different topics into one.

I've added this move configuration to improve the Local Search performance based on the official documentation. I converted these configurations from XML to Java and set the Local Search termination time to 360 unimproved seconds (UnimprovedSecondsSpentLimit). However, Local Search is terminating after one step.
I'm using the Anchor Shadow Variable approach. The planning works fine with a small amount of data but faces issues with larger datasets.
Could you suggest which configurations I should use to ensure Local Search explores more combinations and finds a better solution?
